# javascript friendly replacement for ' character available?

Tags: javascript, xpages

on my xpage I set a javascript variable onload:

```
var custName = '#{javascript: matterBean.getMatter().getCustomer().getCustName();}';
```

this variable I use to replace later the title of a bootstrap dialog.

I notice names with the ' character in it break the code.

I could replace it with

var custName = "#{javascript: matterBean.getMatter().getCustomer().getCustName();}";

but then this would break if the name contains the " character.

Is there an alternative, a javascript friendly replacement so the back-end code (java) could return a javascript friendly replacement for the ' character?

Comment: The OP shouldn't run into this problem at all especially since the OP mentions a backend process which creates the entire code. Assembling the parts without the need of explicitly escaping quotes can be done in any environment like e.g. ... `const test = "I ain't need to be escaped like with \'"; const quotedTest = "'" + test + "'";`. Otherwise escaping was the way to go. JS also has its own [`template literal`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) syntax.

Comment: Look at Apache Commons StringEscapeUtils for escaping the string

Comment: I have added my comment as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Apache Commons StringEscapeUtils for escaping the string. Example:

```
StringEscapeUtils.escapeJavaScript(str);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
StringEscapeUtils.escapeJavaScript(str);
```